# How to get the full certificate path/chain of this file in PowerShell

Tags: powershell, certificate, x509certificate, x509certificate2, powershell-7.3

I have a signed file that for some reason can't get its root certificate in PowerShell using the code below

```
$FilePath = '.\NordPassSetup_x86.exe'

# Get the certificate from the file path
$Cert = New-Object System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate2 $FilePath

# Build the certificate chain
$Chain = New-Object System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Chain
[void]$Chain.Build($Cert)

$Chain.ChainElements.count

foreach ($Element in $Chain.ChainElements) {
    $Element.Certificate | ft -AutoSize
}
```

Uploaded the file here: https://ufile.io/1j5pleow

The output is 3 items instead of 4 items. The file has 1 leaf, 1 root and 2 intermediate certificates.

I've tried skipping check for root cert and setting the check to offline but didn't help

```
[System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509RevocationMode]::Offline

[System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509RevocationFlag]::ExcludeRoot
```

The highlighted certificate doesn't show up in command line

[image]

Comment: Do you have all of the intermediate and root certificates installed on the system where you are running this code?

Comment: I tried exporting the root certificate and installed it in personal store and trusted root certificate authorities but didn't help. It is necessary if i just want to list the certificates in PowerShell ?

Comment: I don't know, it was just a guess. FYI, I can reproduce the issue using your code (Win 10 Pro 22H2). A chain of 4 certificates is shown by the Windows property dialog, while your code only shows 3.

Comment: Glad to know you can reproduce it, I use Windows 11 22H2 and tried it on clean VM with the same OS too. Haven't found any other file with this behavior. kinda an edge case, really want to know how it can hide its root certificate like that. The code I used is just one variation of many codes I tried and I don't even need to make this particular code work. Just any method using PowerShell/.NET that can show me the full certificate chain of this file is acceptable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally figured out a way to do this and it works beautifully. Leaf certificate, Root certificate, Intermediate certificate(s) and nested certificates are all detected and processed. The code is part of my module and available here:

https://github.com/HotCakeX/Harden-Windows-Security/blob/main/WDACConfig/Invoke-WDACSimulation.psm1

First I made this function to get the certificate collection of the signed file

```
function Get-SignedFileCertificates {
    param (
        # Define two sets of parameters, one for the FilePath and one for the CertObject
        [Parameter()]
        [string]$FilePath,
        [Parameter(ValueFromPipeline = $true)]       
        [System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate2]$X509Certificate2
    )

    # Create an X509Certificate2Collection object
    $CertCollection = New-Object System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate2Collection

    # Check which parameter set is used
    if ($FilePath) {
        # If the FilePath parameter is used, import all the certificates from the file
        $CertCollection.Import($FilePath, $null, 'DefaultKeySet')
    }
    elseif ($X509Certificate2) {
        # If the CertObject parameter is used, add the certificate object to the collection
        $CertCollection.Add($X509Certificate2)
    }

    # Return the collection
    return $CertCollection
}
```

Then I modified one of my previous functions accordingly to handle the new type of data

```
function Get-CertificateDetails {
    param (
        [Parameter(ParameterSetName = 'Based on File Path', Mandatory = $true)]
        [System.String]$FilePath,

        [Parameter(ParameterSetName = 'Based on Certificate', Mandatory = $true)]
        $X509Certificate2,    

        [Parameter(ParameterSetName = 'Based on Certificate')]    
        [System.String]$LeafCNOfTheNestedCertificate, # This is used only for when -X509Certificate2 parameter is used, so that we can filter out the Leaf certificate and only get the Intermediate certificates at the end of this function     
        
        [Parameter(ParameterSetName = 'Based on File Path')]
        [Parameter(ParameterSetName = 'Based on Certificate')]
        [switch]$IntermediateOnly,

        [Parameter(ParameterSetName = 'Based on File Path')]
        [Parameter(ParameterSetName = 'Based on Certificate')]
        [switch]$LeafCertificate
    )

    # An array to hold objects
    [System.Object[]]$Obj = @()

    if ($FilePath) {
        # Get all the certificates from the file path using the Get-SignedFileCertificates function
        $CertCollection = Get-SignedFileCertificates -FilePath $FilePath | Where-Object { $_.EnhancedKeyUsageList.FriendlyName -ne 'Time Stamping' }
    }
    else {
        # The "| Where-Object {$_ -ne 0}" part is used to filter the output coming from Get-AuthenticodeSignatureEx function that gets nested certificate
        $CertCollection = Get-SignedFileCertificates -X509Certificate2 $X509Certificate2 | Where-Object { $_.EnhancedKeyUsageList.FriendlyName -ne 'Time Stamping' } | Where-Object { $_ -ne 0 }
    }

    # Loop through each certificate in the collection and call this function recursively with the certificate object as an input
    foreach ($Cert in $CertCollection) {
                      
        # Build the certificate chain
        $Chain = New-Object -TypeName System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Chain

        # Set the chain policy properties
        $chain.ChainPolicy.RevocationMode = 'NoCheck'
        $chain.ChainPolicy.RevocationFlag = 'EndCertificateOnly'
        $chain.ChainPolicy.VerificationFlags = 'NoFlag'

        [void]$Chain.Build($Cert)      
        
        # If AllCertificates is present, loop through all chain elements and display all certificates
        foreach ($Element in $Chain.ChainElements) {
            # Create a custom object with the certificate properties

            # Extract the data after CN= in the subject and issuer properties
            # When a common name contains a comma ',' then it will automatically be wrapped around double quotes. E.g., "Skylum Software USA, Inc."
            # The methods below are conditional regex. Different patterns are used based on the availability of at least one double quote in the CN field, indicating that it had comma in it so it had been enclosed with double quotes by system

            $Element.Certificate.Subject -match 'CN=(?<InitialRegexTest2>.*?),.*' | Out-Null
            $SubjectCN = $matches['InitialRegexTest2'] -like '*"*' ? ($Element.Certificate.Subject -split 'CN="(.+?)"')[1] : $matches['InitialRegexTest2']
            
            $Element.Certificate.Issuer -match 'CN=(?<InitialRegexTest3>.*?),.*' | Out-Null
            $IssuerCN = $matches['InitialRegexTest3'] -like '*"*' ? ($Element.Certificate.Issuer -split 'CN="(.+?)"')[1] : $matches['InitialRegexTest3']
            
            # Get the TBS value of the certificate using the Get-TBSCertificate function
            $TbsValue = Get-TBSCertificate -cert $Element.Certificate
            # Create a custom object with the extracted properties and the TBS value
            $Obj += [pscustomobject]@{
                SubjectCN = $SubjectCN
                IssuerCN  = $IssuerCN
                NotAfter  = $element.Certificate.NotAfter
                TBSValue  = $TbsValue                
            }           
        }  
    }

    if ($FilePath) {

        # The reason the commented code below is not used is because some files such as C:\Windows\System32\xcopy.exe or d3dcompiler_47.dll that are signed by Microsoft report a different Leaf certificate common name when queried using Get-AuthenticodeSignature
        # (Get-AuthenticodeSignature -FilePath $FilePath).SignerCertificate.Subject -match 'CN=(?<InitialRegexTest4>.*?),.*' | Out-Null

        $CertificateUsingAlternativeMethod = [System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate]::CreateFromSignedFile($FilePath)
        $CertificateUsingAlternativeMethod.Subject -match 'CN=(?<InitialRegexTest4>.*?),.*' | Out-Null

        
        [string]$TestAgainst = $matches['InitialRegexTest4'] -like '*"*' ? ((Get-AuthenticodeSignature -FilePath $FilePath).SignerCertificate.Subject -split 'CN="(.+?)"')[1] : $matches['InitialRegexTest4']
         

        if ($IntermediateOnly) {

            $FinalObj = $Obj | 
            Where-Object { $_.SubjectCN -ne $_.IssuerCN } | # To omit Root certificate from the result
            Where-Object { $_.SubjectCN -ne $TestAgainst } | # To omit the Leaf certificate
            Group-Object -Property TBSValue | ForEach-Object { $_.Group[0] } # To make sure the output values are unique based on TBSValue property

            return $FinalObj

        }
        elseif ($LeafCertificate) {
    
            $FinalObj = $Obj | 
            Where-Object { $_.SubjectCN -ne $_.IssuerCN } | # To omit Root certificate from the result
            Where-Object { $_.SubjectCN -eq $TestAgainst } | # To get the Leaf certificate
            Group-Object -Property TBSValue | ForEach-Object { $_.Group[0] } # To make sure the output values are unique based on TBSValue property

            return $FinalObj
        }

    } 
    # If nested certificate is being processed and X509Certificate2 object is passed
    elseif ($X509Certificate2) {
    
        if ($IntermediateOnly) {

            $FinalObj = $Obj | 
            Where-Object { $_.SubjectCN -ne $_.IssuerCN } | # To omit Root certificate from the result            
            Where-Object { $_.SubjectCN -ne $LeafCNOfTheNestedCertificate } | # To omit the Leaf certificate
            Group-Object -Property TBSValue | ForEach-Object { $_.Group[0] } # To make sure the output values are unique based on TBSValue property

            return $FinalObj

        }  
        elseif ($LeafCertificate) {

            $FinalObj = $Obj | 
            Where-Object { $_.SubjectCN -ne $_.IssuerCN } | # To omit Root certificate from the result
            Where-Object { $_.SubjectCN -eq $LeafCNOfTheNestedCertificate } | # To get the Leaf certificate
            Group-Object -Property TBSValue | ForEach-Object { $_.Group[0] } # To make sure the output values are unique based on TBSValue property

            return $FinalObj

        }        
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This seems to be expected and by design.

Certificate chaining engine in signature validation context uses certificates stored in signature as much as possible. It will look into external stores only when matching certificate is not found.

What happens here: both chains share same intermediate CA certificate (`GlobalSign Extended Validation CodeSigning CA - SHA256 - G3`). Then, signature contains another intermediate CA certificate (`GlobalSign`) which is the issuer of EV code signing CA, so signature validator uses it. And the issuer is `GlobalSign Root CA R1`. This effectively produces a chain of 4 elements (from root to leaf):

- `GlobalSign Root CA - R1`
- `GlobalSign`
- `GlobalSign Extended Validation CodeSigning CA - SHA256 - G3`
- `TEFINCOM S.A.`

The presence of 2nd certificate in signature forces the signature validator to use it, thus extending the chain by one element.

The `X509Chain` doesn't stick to this requirement and builds as many chains as possible and then select the best one, which is then returned to the caller.

Underneath, `X509Chain` will produce these two chains, one that ends up with `GlobalSign Root CA - R1` and another one that ends up with `GlobalSign Root CA - R3`. Both chains are valid, but 2nd chain is shorter (better) and certificate chaining engine returns it. Both, `GlobalSign Root CA - R1` and `GlobalSign Root CA - R3` share the same public key, thus both can be used to validate the chain.

If that extra `GlobalSign` certificate would absent in signature, then both, signature UI viewer and `X509Chain` will return identical chains.

Comment: When you use the word "chain" I'm not sure what you refer to exactly. Because I only see one chain, if the file had 2 chains that'd mean it's double signed, but this file isn't double signed. Also I've tested thousands of files and this file stands out, the code is just a sample part of a big module. Also my question is how I can get the full certificate chain in PowerShell but you didn't show me a way to do that, is there even a way to see all those 4 certificates in PowerShell just like we can see them in file explorer?

Comment: Once I can access all of the certificates in PowerShell just like I can see them in file explorer, then I can properly detect intermediate certificates by omitting last and first certificate in the path/chain and then taking anything that is left as intermediate. This file doesn't allow me to do that. I need to tell PowerShell/.NET to always choose the longest chain so that it will include everything.

Comment: `Because I only see one chain` -- yes, because `X509Chain` returns only one chain which is the best one. You cannot override this behavior. Though if you want to look into all simple chains, then you need to interop `CertGetCertificateChain` unmanaged function.

Comment: Do you know how to do that? also I use your code for detecting nested certificate of double signed files and this question helps with the same task. https://github.com/HotCakeX/Harden-Windows-Security/wiki/Invoke-WDACSimulation#external-licenses

Comment: I think, you should start a new question on using unmanaged function in PowerShell.

Comment: Thank you, i just did: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77051506/how-to-use-unmanaged-function-in-powershell-to-get-all-the-chains-in-this-signed