# How to use unmanaged function in PowerShell to get all the chains in this signed file?

Tags: powershell, function, x509certificate, unmanaged, x509certificate2

I have this file: https://ufile.io/1j5pleow

it has 4 certificates in its path.

Using this method

```
$FilePath = '.\NordPassSetup_x86.exe'

# Get the certificate from the file path
$Cert = New-Object System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate2 $FilePath

# Build the certificate chain
$Chain = New-Object System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Chain
[void]$Chain.Build($Cert)

$Chain.ChainElements.count

foreach ($Element in $Chain.ChainElements) {
    $Element.Certificate | ft -AutoSize
}
```

Only returns the shortest chain which only include 3 certificates, but in file explorer I can see the longest/full chain of the certificates, which are 4.

[image]

I have other files with similar behavior, one of them has 5 certificates but in PowerShell I can only see 3, because it's the shortest chain.

The question is related to [this other one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77031733/how-to-get-the-full-certificate-path-chain-of-this-file-in-powershell). I was told it's possible to do this using `CertGetCertificateChain` unmanaged function.

Comment: You'll have to use C# code in order to perform a P/Invoke call to the [`CertGetCertificateChain`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/wincrypt/nf-wincrypt-certgetcertificatechain) WinAPI function. Ad hoc you can use `Add-Type` to compile such C# code; alternatively, ship your module with a pre-compiled assembly. For a simple example of a P/Invoke call with `Add-Type`, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64406240/45375).

Comment: The certificate in the screenshot does not appear to be the certificate from the linked file. The one in the screenshot appears to have been signed in May 2021, and deriving trust from GlobalSign R1, whereas the one extracted from the executable was signed in May 2019, hierarchy ending at GlobalSign R3

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen we can only see the full certificate chain/path in file explorer. In PowerShell we only see the shortest chain, according to this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/77033530/21243735

Comment: @mklement0 Thanks, that answer was helpful for understanding what they are. I want to use `Add-Type` for Ad hoc method, I just need to know the code to use.

Comment: Usually, [pinvoke.net](https://pinvoke.net/) is a good resource for finding P/Invoke declarations for WinAPI functions, but `CertGetCertificateChain` isn't covered. Perhaps [this](https://bytes.com/topic/c-sharp/answers/276116-using-p-invoke-certfindcertificateinstore) can be a starting point. I suggest giving it a shot and asking a focused question if and when you get stuck.